# Authentication Failure when using external JWT token in SurrealDB

Tags: surrealdb

Can anyone help me setup authentication using external jwt token

So far i have tried multiple variants of the following.

First i define the token using

```
DEFINE TOKEN my_token ON DATABASE TYPE HS512 VALUE '1234567890';
```

Then i generate a token using the above '1234567890' and following header fields.

```
{
  "alg": "HS512",
  "typ": "JWT",
  "NS": "help",
  "DB": "help",
  "TK": "my_token"
}
```

Note: i have also tried defining the "NS","DB","TK" fields in the Payload section of token.

Then i try to authenticate using the token in JS client and http request with Bearer authorization header.

```
db.authenticate("eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsIk5TIjoiaGVscCIsIkRCIjoiaGVscCIsIlRLIjoibXlfdG9rZW4ifQ.e30.uoJypJ-Y9OrZjQW6WtuZWmFYBEOCHlkutbR6mlEYPCHvb49h9nFiWshKDc464MD3jaBh69T1OLwZ2aUWNujiuw")
```

Getting error on both Js client and Http Request

```
name: "AuthenticationError"
message: "There was a problem with authentication"
stack: "AuthenticationError: There was a problem with authentication\n    at Surreal.
```

Comment: NS, DB, TK should definitely be in the data field, header field should only contain info about algortihm and token type.
You can also debug jwt at the official webpage at https://jwt.io/

Comment: Yes. i tried with those fields in the payload as well. but no success. i also tried with the alternative version ("https://surrealdb.com/ns": "help",
  "https://surrealdb.com/db": "help") as well. also most test tokens were generated on jwt.io

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This answer ended up being more comprehensive than originally intended. As such, here's a list of contents to help you find what you're looking for. Unfortunately it seems to be impossible to convert them to links. (Sorry)

### Table of Contents

- Composing a JWT Token

  - Parts of a Token

    - Token Header
    - Token Payload
    - Token Signature
  - Encoding The Token

    - Example: Step-by-step
    - Using NodeJs
- SurrealDB Token Authentication

  - Defining a Token Handler
  - Using The Token We Made
  - Using Public Key Cryptography
- SurrealDB Permissions

  - Token Types

    - Namespace Token
    - Database Token
    - Scope Token
  - Table Permissions

    - FULL: Available to Query Without Any Authentication
    - NONE: Restricted Tables (Implicit Default)
    - Granular Table Permissions
    - Granular Field Permissions
  - Accessing Token & Auth Data from Queries
- Further Reading

### Composing a JWT Token

Now we need to generate a token to test it with. A Json Web Token (JWT), as you may know, consists of three parts: The header, the payload, and the signature. It's base64url encoded (a form of base64 encoding that uses characters safe to use in a web address or hyperlink).

#### Parts of a token

##### Token Header

The header describes to the verifying party, in this case SurrealDB, what kind of token it is and what algorithm it uses. Let's create that:

```json
{
    "alg": "HS512",
    "typ": "JWT",
}
```

##### Token Payload

Now, the payload is the fun part.

For use with SurrealDB, there are a number of fields which determine how the database will process the token.

The types of token allowed by SurrealDB as of version `surreal-1.0.0-beta.8` are as follows:

- scope token authentication: (`ns, db, sc, tk [, id]`)
- database token authentication: (`ns, db, tk`)
- namespace token authentication: (`ns, tk`)

For details, see:
[Token Verification Logic - SurrealDB - GitHub](https://github.com/surrealdb/surrealdb/blob/main/src/iam/verify.rs)

The listed fields are names of:

- `ns :string` Namespace
- `db :string` Database
- `sc :string` Scope
- `tk :string` Token
- `id ?:string` Thing (table row) representing a user (optional)

There are also a number of publicly registered field names with various meanings - relevant in case you want interoperability or standardisation; less so for simply working with SurrealDB. You can put any serialisable data you want into the payload. Keep in mind, however, that that data will be sent many times over the network so it's worth keeping it short.

If you're curious:
[List of publicly registered JWT fields - maintained by IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/jwt/jwt.xhtml)

Let's create a database token. When we registered it, we called it `my_token` so let's add that as our `tk` field, adding our `db` and `ns` as in your question. The fields are not case-sensitive as SurrealDB sees them, however they will be if you try to access the payload data directly later, as part of a permission or select query.

```json
{
    "ns": "help",
    "db": "help",
    "tk": "my_token",
    "someOtherValue": "justToShowThatWeCan"
}
```

##### Token Signature

Once we have composed the header and payload, the last step in creating a token is to sign it.

The signature is composed by:

- removing the whitespace of; and
- base64url encoding the header and payload; then
- concatenating them with a dot (period/full-stop) separating them.

The whole string is passed through the (in this case HMAC_SHA512) hashing algorithm along with the secret key, and then the result is base64url encoded to form the signature.

In case you're interested in more depth:
[How HMAC combines the key with the data - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC)

Let's see it in action:

#### Encoding The Token

##### Example: Step-by-step

1. **The encoded header**
   `eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9`
2. **The encoded payload**
   `eyJucyI6ImhlbHAiLCJkYiI6ImhlbHAiLCJ0ayI6Im15X3Rva2VuIiwic29tZU90aGVyVmFsdWUiOiJqdXN0VG9TaG93VGhhdFdlQ2FuIn0`
3. **Concatenate separated by a dot**
   `eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJucyI6ImhlbHAiLCJkYiI6ImhlbHAiLCJ0ayI6Im15X3Rva2VuIiwic29tZU90aGVyVmFsdWUiOiJqdXN0VG9TaG93VGhhdFdlQ2FuIn0`
4. **Hash the result, with the secret key to get:**
   `8nBoXQQ_Up3HGKBB64cKekw906zES8GXa6QZYygYWD5GbFoLlcPe2RtMMSAzRrHHfGRsHz9F5hJ1CMfaDDy5AA`
5. **Append the key to the input, again with a dot**
   `eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJucyI6ImhlbHAiLCJkYiI6ImhlbHAiLCJ0ayI6Im15X3Rva2VuIiwic29tZU90aGVyVmFsdWUiOiJqdXN0VG9TaG93VGhhdFdlQ2FuIn0.8nBoXQQ_Up3HGKBB64cKekw906zES8GXa6QZYygYWD5GbFoLlcPe2RtMMSAzRrHHfGRsHz9F5hJ1CMfaDDy5AA`

And that's our complete token!

You can use [jwt.io](https://jwt.io) to play around with payloads, headers, and signature algorithms.

##### Using NodeJs

If you just want to encode tokens on Node.js, I would recommend the package: [npm - jsonwebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken)

```bash
npm i jsonwebtoken
```

```js
import jwt, { JwtPayload } from 'jsonwebtoken';

// Typescript Types
type signTokenFn = (payload:object, secretOrPrivateKey:string, options?:object) => Promise<string>;
type verifyTokenFn = (token:string, secretOrPublicKey:string, options?:object) => Promise<string | JwtPayload>;

// Let's make them await-able
const promisifyCallback = (resolve, reject) => (failure, success) => failure ? reject(failure) : resolve(success);

const signToken:signTokenFn = async (payload, secretOrPrivateKey, options = {}) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    jwt.sign(payload, secretOrPrivateKey, options, promisifyCallback(resolve, reject));
});

const verifyToken:verifyTokenFn = async (token, secretOrPublicKey, options = {}) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    jwt.verify(token, secretOrPublicKey, options, (err, decoded) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(decoded));
});

// The actual encoding/verifying
const secret = '0123456789';

const tokenPayload = {
    ns: "help",
    db: "help",
    tk: "my_token",
    someOtherValue: "justToShowThatWeCan"
};

const signedToken = await signToken(tokenPayload, secret, { 
    expiresIn: '10m' // Set any duration here ex: '24h'
});

const accessDecoded = await verifyToken(signedToken, secret)
```

---

### SurrealDB Token Authentication

#### Defining a Token Handler

You're correct in your question about how to define the token handler, so let's do that:

```sql
DEFINE TOKEN my_token ON DATABASE TYPE HS512 VALUE '1234567890';
```

A token can be defined on a namespace (ns), database (db), or scope. The latter is as yet undocumented, as it's one of the recent commits to the codebase. See:
[Commit (`75d1e86`) `"Add DEFINE TOKEN … ON SCOPE … functionality"` - SurrealDB on GitHub](https://github.com/surrealdb/surrealdb/commit/75d1e869907ed2e0e5fffa0f145f2060b2f23c2f)

#### Using The Token We Made

Using the vs-code REST client, we can test our token as such:

```http
POST /sql HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8000
Content-Type: text/plain
Accept: application/json
Token: eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJucyI6ImhlbHAiLCJkYiI6ImhlbHAiLCJ0ayI6Im15X3Rva2VuIiwic29tZU90aGVyVmFsdWUiOiJqdXN0VG9TaG93VGhhdFdlQ2FuIn0.8nBoXQQ_Up3HGKBB64cKekw906zES8GXa6QZYygYWD5GbFoLlcPe2RtMMSAzRrHHfGRsHz9F5hJ1CMfaDDy5AA
NS: help
DB: help

SELECT * FROM myHelpTable
```

We should get a response like this:

```http
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-type: application/json
version: surreal-1.0.0-beta.8+20220930.c246533
server: SurrealDB
content-length: 91
date: Tue, 03 Jan 2023 00:09:49 GMT

[
  {
    "time": "831.535µs",
    "status": "OK",
    "result": [
      {
        "id": "test:record"
      },
      {
        "id": "test:record2"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Now that we know it's working, let's try it out with the javascript client library. (This is the same for Node.JS)

```js
import Surreal from 'surrealdb.js';

const db = new Surreal('http://127.0.0.1:8000/rpc');
const NS = 'help';
const DB = 'help';

async function main() {
    await db.authenticate('eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJucyI6ImhlbHAiLCJkYiI6ImhlbHAiLCJ0ayI6Im15X3Rva2VuIiwic29tZU90aGVyVmFsdWUiOiJqdXN0VG9TaG93VGhhdFdlQ2FuIn0.8nBoXQQ_Up3HGKBB64cKekw906zES8GXa6QZYygYWD5GbFoLlcPe2RtMMSAzRrHHfGRsHz9F5hJ1CMfaDDy5AA');

    await db.use(NS, DB);
    const result = await db.select('test');

    console.log(result);
    // [
    //   { id: 'test:record' },
    //   { id: 'test:record2' }
    // ]
}
main();
```

#### Using Public Key Cryptography

If you want, you can also use a public/private key-pair to allow for verifying tokens without the need to share the secret needed to generate authentic tokens.

```js
import crypto from 'node:crypto';

// Generate Fresh RSA Keys for Access Tokens on Startup
const { publicKey, privateKey } = crypto.generateKeyPairSync('rsa', {
    modulusLength: 4096,
    publicKeyEncoding: { type: 'spki', format: 'pem' },
    privateKeyEncoding: { type: 'pkcs8', format: 'pem' },
});

async function main() {
    // Add our public key to SurrealDB as the verifier
    await db.query(`DEFINE TOKEN my_token ON DATABASE TYPE RS256 VALUE "${publicKey}";`).then(() => 

    console.log('yay!');
}
main();
```

### SurrealDB Permissions

As mentioned above, there are three types of tokens which can be defined and used to authenticate queries.

#### Token Types

##### Namespace Token

```sql
-- Will apply to the current namespace
DEFINE TOKEN @name ON NAMESPACE TYPE @algorithm VALUE @secretOrPublicKey;

-- Can also be abbreviated:
DEFINE TOKEN @name ON NS TYPE @algorithm VALUE @secretOrPublicKey;
```

***Warning: Table and field permissions will not be processed when executing queries for namespace token bearers.***

This type of token gives the authenticated user or system the ability to access the entire namespace on which the token is defined.

That includes select, create, update, and delete (SCUD) access to all tables in all databases, as well as the ability to define and remove databases and tables.

##### Database Token

```sql
-- Will apply to the current database
DEFINE TOKEN @name ON DATABASE TYPE @algorithm VALUE @secretOrPublicKey;

-- Can also be abbreviated:
DEFINE TOKEN @name ON DB TYPE @algorithm VALUE @secretOrPublicKey;
```

***Warning: Table and field permissions will not be processed when executing queries for database token bearers.***

This type of token gives the authenticated user or system the ability to access the entire database on which the token is defined.

That includes select, create, update, and delete (SCUD) access to all tables in the specific database, as well as the ability to define and remove tables.

##### Scope Token

```sql
-- Requires a defined scope on which to define the token; scope is defined as a property on the current database.
DEFINE SCOPE @name;

-- Define the token after we define the scope:
DEFINE TOKEN @name ON SCOPE @name TYPE @algorithm VALUE @secretOrPublicKey;
```

***Table and field permissions will be processed as normal when executing queries for scope token bearers.***

This type of token gives the authenticated user or system the ability to access the database on which the scope is defined, but only to the extent permitted by permissions defined for tables and fields.

That includes select, create, update, and delete (SCUD) access to all tables (permissions allowing) in the specific database, however scoped tokens may not create, modify, view info for, nor delete tables.

The optional `id` parameter in the payload allows a scope token to be linked to a table row. This could be for a user account, a client id for batch or automated systems, etc. The semantics is up to you. In table permissions, the id can be accessed via `$token.id` and the row pointed to can be accessed via `$auth`.

#### Table Permissions

##### FULL: Available to Query Without Any Authentication

```sql
DEFINE TABLE this_table_is_publicly_accessible;
```

When you define a table, note that if you do not define any permissions for it, the default is accessible to the public - ie without any kind of authentication.

***Keep in mind that using `strict` mode, you will need to explicitly define your tables before you can use them. To avoid them being unintentionally made public, always set some kind of permission.***

##### NONE: Restricted Tables (Implicit Default)

```sql
CREATE restricted:hello;

-- The above implicitly creates a table with this definition:
DEFINE TABLE restricted SCHEMALESS PERMISSIONS NONE;
```

If you leave a table undefined, but begin creating entries, thus implicitly creating the table, it is given a default set of permissions allowing no public access and no scoped access. Only database token bearers and namespace token bearers will be able to access the data.

##### Granular Table Permissions

```sql
DEFINE TABLE granular_access SCHEMALESS PERMISSIONS
FOR select FULL
FOR create,update WHERE $token.someOtherValue = "justToShowThatWeCan"
FOR delete NONE;
```

Here we allow public access to select from the table, while only allowing scope users with the "someOtherValue" in their token set to "justToShowThatWeCan" to create and update. Meanwhile nobody with a scoped token may delete. Only Database and Namespace type token bearers may now delete from the table.

##### Granular Field Permissions

```sql
DEFINE field more_granular ON TABLE granular_access PERMISSIONS
FOR select FULL
FOR create,update WHERE $token.someOtherValue = "justToShowThatWeCan"
FOR delete NONE;
```

Similar to full tables, permissions can also be set on single fields.

#### Accessing Token & Auth Data from Queries

The protected params `$session`, `$scope`, `$token`, and `$auth` contain extra information related to the client.

To see what data is available to access, try running the queries:

```sql
SELECT * FROM $session;
SELECT * FROM $token;
SELECT * FROM $scope;
SELECT * FROM $auth;
```

While using a namespace or database token, only the `$session` and `$token` parameters have values. Briefly:

- `$session` an object which contains session data, most useful-seeming being `$session.ip` which shows the client ip and outgoing port of the connection to SurrealDB. example: `127.0.0.1:60497`
- `$token` makes available all of the fields present in the payload of the JWT token used to authenticate the session, as an object.
- `$scope` seems to simply contain the name of the scope to which the user/client has access.
- `$auth` is present when the scoped JWT also contains an `id` field, and contains the data from the table row specified by `id`. For example if `id` contains `users:some_row_id` then `$auth` will contain the row pointed to, if it exists, and if the scope has permission to access this row. Fields can be hidden from this object using permissions as well.

### Further Reading

- [SurrealDB - Features page (contains code examples)](https://surrealdb.com/features)
- [SurrealDB Docs - DEFINE statements](https://surrealdb.com/docs/surrealql/statements/define)

  - Note that the documentation does not, as of this writing, show the ability to define a token upon a scope. It is, however, valid and tested as shown.
- [SurrealDB Commit - defining token on scope](https://github.com/surrealdb/surrealdb/commit/75d1e869907ed2e0e5fffa0f145f2060b2f23c2f)
- [SurrealDB Codebase - parsing logic for DEFINE statements](https://github.com/surrealdb/surrealdb/blob/main/lib/src/sql/statements/define.rs)
- [SurrealDB Codebase - parsing logic for PERMISSIONS](https://github.com/surrealdb/surrealdb/blob/main/lib/src/sql/permission.rs)
- [SurrealDB Codebase - token verification logic](https://github.com/surrealdb/surrealdb/blob/main/src/iam/verify.rs)
- [NPM Package - jsonwebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken)
- [JWT.io - JSON Web Tokens (encoder/decoder)](https://jwt.io)
- [Wikipedia - HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC)

Comment: Thank you @Jeramy for the very detailed answer. 

i was able to find the issue by adding some logs to the source code and compiling locally. The issue was i did not include the token expiry (`exp`) and `iat` fields in the token but Surreal actually checks these fields as well to verify the token. And instead of saying if the token has expired or when these fields are missing.. Surreal just throws a general `AuthenticationError`.  The documentation as of now does not mention the extra checks done by the SurrealDB.

Comment: Thanks for figuring this out @Jeremy. This makes it super easy to understand how to integrate identity providers into SurrealDB.

Comment: @Ashamnx I can confirm that `iat` and `exp` are not required on the version of SurrealDB I'm running: `surreal 1.0.0-beta.8+20220930.c246533 for macos on x86_64` however if they are on yours, that might be a bug for one of us. I tested with exactly the token setup as described, which notably lacks either field, and it worked.

Comment: Damn... I learned more from this answer than from the entire surreal docs. Thank you.

Comment: Second @Ashamnx, `exp` solved the authentication error in `1.0.0-beta.9+20230402.5eafebd for macos on aarch64`, `iat` are not required.

Comment: Can you make it more explicit `FOR create,update WHERE $token.someOtherValue = "justToShowThatWeCan"`. Have a table which user can create and want other users to be given permission for edits like google doc

Comment: Adding the `--auth` flag on start seems to cause an IAM error: `{"code":403,"details":"Forbidden","description":"Not allowed to do this.","information":"There was a problem with the database: IAM error: Not enough permissions to perform this action"}` How can I fix this? I have even tried `PERMISSIONS FULL` for the table I try to access using token auth, but the same error occurs.